# Galaxy S2 X t989d firmware update - Kies crashes

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-kies, device-firmware

I am trying to apply Jelly Bean firmware update on my Galaxy S2 X, but everytime I try to, Kies dies at 0% of the firmware update, without any error message.

I tried uninstalling and installing Kies again. It is up to date. I also tried running it in Windows 7 mode and XP SP3 mode (I'm on Windows 8 64-bit).

I did a factory reset of my cellphone, and still encounter the problem.

Is there any alternative or way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actualy got it by doing the update from a Windows 7 computer. Kies seems to have difficulties with Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Kies sucks horribly. The only way I've gotten it to work is to run it in `Compatible with Windows XP (Service Pack 3)` and running it as a administrator. It should work fine then.